# Producing a Circular Rose plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Good afternoon,

I have a simple dataset with 2 columns with wind direction and data. I am trying to reproduce a plot similar to the following:

[image]

After searching in the stackoverflow I have come across the "circular" package 'rose-diag' function.

however when I try it with the following codes:

```
x= dat$Test

plot(x)
rose.diag(x, bins=24, main="test", prop=2, axes = F)
```

I get the following:

[image]

which shows wrong directions. Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong here and any suggestion to rectify the error?

I also found some examples in ggplot but could not workout with what I am trying to do. any suggestion would be really appreciated too with any alternative method available just to learn other ways of doing this type of plots. thanks

my sample input data that I am testing with are:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(wd = c(7.5, 22.5, 37.5, 52.5, 67.5, 82.5, 97.5, 
112.5, 127.5, 142.5, 157.5, 172.5, 187.5, 202.5, 217.5, 232.5, 
247.5, 262.5, 277.5, 292.5, 307.5, 322.5, 337.5, 352.5), Test = c(10.82, 
6.75, 6.57, 6.52, 8.48, 9.66, 15.36, 18.97, 29.14, 36.56, 38.65, 
44.23, 51.99, 50.83, 51.93, 50.27, 49.35, 52.67, 54.05, 49.69, 
43.73, 29.83, 18.94, 17.33)), .Names = c("wd", "Test"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: check [ggplot coord_polar](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_polar.html) the wind rose part

Comment: I was just reading through that! thanks for your example I can use this to adopt to what I am after. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some example code:

```
df <- data.frame(wd = c(7.5, 22.5, 37.5, 52.5, 67.5, 82.5, 97.5, 
                 112.5, 127.5, 142.5, 157.5, 172.5, 187.5, 202.5, 217.5, 232.5, 
                 247.5, 262.5, 277.5, 292.5, 307.5, 322.5, 337.5, 352.5), 
          Test = c(10.82, 
                   6.75, 6.57, 6.52, 8.48, 9.66, 15.36, 18.97, 29.14, 36.56, 38.65, 
                   44.23, 51.99, 50.83, 51.93, 50.27, 49.35, 52.67, 54.05, 49.69, 
                   43.73, 29.83, 18.94, 17.33))
ggplot(df, aes(wd, Test)) + 
    geom_bar(width=15, stat='identity', color='grey') + 
    coord_polar()
```